# Detailview and update on the same form django

Tags: python, django

I want to create an update and detailview on the same page but apparently my code below is not working fine with me. Instead on updating the selected `ref_no` it creats a new set of records.

```
class RFPNotificationView(DetailView):
    model = RFP
    template_name = 'home/rfp_notif.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RFPNotificationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rfpapproveform'] = RFPApproveForm(instance=self.kwargs.get('ref_no'))
        return context

    # Add POST method
    def post(self, request, pk):
        post = RFP.objects.get(ref_no=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form = RFPApproveForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.post = post
            obj.current_approver = self.request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('home-page')
```

Comment: add instance and try, form = RFPApproveForm(request.POST, instance=post)

Comment: same result. it's still creating new record.

Comment: if not working there is another convenience method, get_or_create, try that way

Comment: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
i am receiving this error.